# How can I prove that a function has a certain bound on an interval?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, upper-lower-bounds

To preface this, I have had calculus, but not analysis. I am working on a discrete dynamical system which gives rise to the function
$f(x) = (-x^2-x+1)(e^{-x^2})$.

I need to show that $|f(x)|<1$ for all values $x > 0$. I know that this is true from plotting the function, but I have no idea how to begin approaching this formally (probably because I haven't had any training in analysis). How do I approach this proof?

Comment: You can start by finding the critical points and drawing a sign diagram of the derivative. However, I suspect you have tried that already, so where do you have problems then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $e^{x^2}$ is positive, we can multiply through on both sides to see that 
$$
|f(x)|\leq 1\iff |1-x-x^2|\leq e^{x^2}.
$$
For $x\geq 0$ (the domain you are interested in), obviously $1-x-x^2\leq 1$. Since $1\leq e^{x^2}$ for all $x$,
$$
1-x-x^2\leq 1\leq e^{x^2},
$$
proving half of the inequality. For the other half, we must show that
$$
x^2+x-1\leq e^{x^2},
$$
which can by handled by using the inequality $e^y\geq y+1$ valid for all $y\geq 0$.

Specifically, for $x\leq 1$ we can take $y=x^2$ to conclude that
$$
x^2+x-1\leq x^2+1\leq e^{x^2},
$$
whereas for $x\geq 1$ we can take $y=x^2-1$ to conclude that
$$
x^2+x-1\leq 2x^2\leq ex^2\leq e\cdot e^{x^2-1}=e^{x^2},
$$
as desired.

Comment: The last line (before I edited my answer) stated that the inequality $e^y\geq y+1$ could be used to finish up. I filled in the details in my edit.

Comment: This looks great